# Get Base64 String from an HTTP request

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function `getImageAsBlob` that uses `HttpClient` to get the image as Blob and function `toBase64` which converts the retrieved blob into a base64 string.

How do I chain the functions in order to get the base64 string given that I have only the URL of the image? Thanks for the help!

Below are the functions:

```
toBase64(blob: Blob): Observable<string> {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        return fromEvent(reader, 'load')
          .pipe(map(() => (reader.result as string)))
    }
```

```
getImageAsBlob(url: string): Observable<Blob>{
        return this.http.get(url,{responseType:'blob'})
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to *subscribe* to **getImageAsBlob** and on next callback , you could call your function in order to create your image. Something like:

```
    this.getImageAsBlob('url').subscribe(img => {
    this.toBase64(img);
  }, 
    err => console.log('Error', err),
    () => console.log('Completed');
);
```

More information about Subscribers can be found here: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscriber
@AlexCano

Comment: How can I assign a variable with the result?

Comment: first of all you have to define/initialize a variable in your TS Class. For example `image : string = ' ';`  _// just empty string to hold your image_ . After that you could just assign this.image = reader.result .  At the end you could just do something like ` <img [src]="image" />` in your **Template** @AlexCano If my answers help you, just vote for them this will help to other users with same question.

Comment: I put the function in a service. Do I need to change the return value of my function? Sorry for asking too much.

Comment: @AlexCano nope,  the return value should be the same. More info about the services in Angular [link](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#why-services)

Answer (score 0):

```js
getImageAsBlob("url")
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(blobResponse => toBase64(blobResponse)
  )
  .subscribe(img => ...)
```

Comment: If I have to assign it into a variable, I do it after the => subscribe?